# JBoss Fuse doesn't want to deploy...waiting for namespace handlers [http://cxf.apache.org/core]

Tags: java, jboss, jbossfuse

When I try to add this code to blueprint

```
<cxfcore:bus>
    <cxfcore:features>
        <p:policies/>
        <cxfcore:logging/>
    </cxf:features>
</cxfcore:bus>
```

with namespace xmlns:cxfcore="http://cxf.apache.org/core" then in logs I can see:

```
18:26:59,058 | INFO  | Thread-47        | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 9 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.0.1.redhat-610379 | Bundle sk.dcom.soa.doubleit is waiting for namespace handlers [http://cxf.apache.org/core]
18:26:59,060 | DEBUG | Thread-47        | doubleit                         | 351 - sk.dcom.soa.doubleit - 0.0.0.local-SNAPSHOT | BundleEvent STARTED - sk.dcom.soa.doubleit
```

but there is nothing started (no cxf endpoint, if there is not `cxfcore:bus` defined then two endpoint are listening).

I can see feature installed:

```
[installed  ] [2.7.0.redhat-610379    ] cxf         cxf-2.7.0.redhat-610379
```

fuse version:

```
jboss-fuse-6.1.0.redhat-379
```

Any clues guys? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will first need to have the camel-blueprint dependency available in the bundle so that the xml namespace can be found. Then you need to use the correct namespace. The correct one is, `xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core"`

An example is:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws"
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core"
    xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
      http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxws.xsd
      http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/core.xsd
      http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd
    ">
```